# Appending elements using jquery is very slow

Tags: php, jquery, html, append, bpopup

I've been using jquery to append/create a table from information retrieved from database. When testing the codes at the localhost, the appending works fine but when I uploaded it trough the  web and try to navigate the site, it seems that the loading of information from the database is slow and when the user clicks the button more than once. The appending also happens more than once. Here is my code:

```
$('.viewemp').live("click", function () {

    empviewmodalctr = 1;

    var userid = $(this).attr("id");

        var empviewdata = {userid:userid,action:"viewempinfo"};

        $.ajax({                        
                url:"../includes/MC.Admin.ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: empviewdata,
                success: function(empinfo) {

                    var empJson = $.parseJSON(empinfo);

                    $("#employeeinfo_tbl").html(empJson.empinfo);   

                    $("#employeeemploymentinfo_tbl").html(empJson.empempinfo);      

            $('#employee-view').bPopup({
                modalClose: false
             });

                }

        });
```

Page:

```
<div id = "employee-view">
<div id = 'employee-view-container'>

    <div id = 'employee-view-container-title'>Employee's Information</div>
    <div class = 'closebtn'><img src = '../images/close.png' style ='"width:100%;height:100%;'/></div>

        <div id = 'employee-view-container-content-left'>

            <table id = 'employeeinfo_tbl'>

            </table>

        </div>

        <div id = 'employee-view-container-content-right'>

            <table id = 'employeeemploymentinfo_tbl'>

             </table>

        </div>

 </div>
```

I got it to work by redesigning my elements and utilizing the ajax call properly and still using .html()

Comment: "it seems that the loading of information from the database is slow and when the user clicks the button more than once" - Why not disable the button before $.ajax, and re-enable it after its complete? Is it really necessarily to call ajax twice, instead of returning all the data you need the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things: disable the button when it initially gets clicked and then re-enable it when the AJAX call has finished, so amend your jquery to this:

```
$('.viewemp').live("click", function () {
    var clicked = this;
    $(clicked).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    empviewmodalctr = 1;
    var userid = $(this).attr("id");
    var empviewdata = {userid:userid,action:"viewempinfo"};
    $.ajax({                        
        url:"../includes/MC.Admin.ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: empviewdata,
        success: function(empinfo) {
            var empJson = $.parseJSON(empinfo);
            $("#employee-view").html("<div id = 'employee-view-container'>"+
            "<div id = 'employee-view-container-title'>Employee's Information</div>"+
            "<div id = 'closebtn'><img src = '../images/closebtn.png' style ='"+                                        "width:100%;height:100%;'/></div></div>");
            var a = "<div id = 'employee-view-container-content-left'></div>"+
            "<div id = 'employee-view-container-content-right'></div>";
            $("#employee-view-container").append(a);
            var b = "<table id = 'employeeinfo_tbl'>";
            $("#employee-view-container-content-left").append(b);
            $("#employeeinfo_tbl").append(empJson.empinfo); 
            var empemploymentviewdata = {userid:userid,action:"viewempemploymentinfo"};

            $.ajax({                        
                url:"../includes/MC.Admin.ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: empemploymentviewdata,
                success: function(empemployment) {
                    var empemploymentJson = $.parseJSON(empemployment);
                    var c = "<table id = 'employeeemploymentinfo_tbl' border = 0>";
                    $("#employee-view-container-content-right").append(c);
                    $("#employeeemploymentinfo_tbl").append(empemploymentJson.empempinfo);
                }
            });
            $("#employee-view-container").append("</table></div>");             
            $('#employee-view').bPopup({
            modalClose: false
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(clicked).removeAttr('disabled', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: May I suggest `.prop('disabled',true)` and `.prop('disabled',false)` (unless using an old version of jQuery)?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Of course you may. Either will work as well as the other. For those who don't know, you can only use prop() with > jquery 1.6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Disabling the click event is not effective. Any ideas? I tried deconstructing the div everytime I click the button yet not effective.

Comment: @ljpv14: glad you got it sorted